# current browser support for html5 video

Tags: html5-video

I have been reading up online, and it seems that all current browsers support video in mp4.

Is this sufficient, or is it still necessary to include the webm format?

Answer (score 0):

H.264 is still not supported in some browsers - like Opera and Firefox (when running on versions of Windows prior to Windows 7). See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4) and [html5test.com](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/video-h264/video-webmvp8.html) to see a full breakdown. But it doesn't seem like a huge loss to drop those users.

Comment: Sorry - I just noticed your reply. Yes, this helps very much. Thank you!!